# NullReferenceException with static class property

Tags: c#, static, nullreferenceexception

I have a static class that looks like this:

```
namespace Argus
{
    static class Argus
    {
        public static List<Branch> myArgus;
    }
}
```

and elsewhere in my code I have this:

```
// Add this branch to myArgus
Argus.myArgus.Add(branch);
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have verified that `branch` is valid (it's an object of the `Branch` class), and have no idea what could be wrong here. I'm trying to read branch data in from a text file.

Comment: Why would `myArgus` ever be non-null? Also: don't do this. Static state like this is almost always really really really bad idea (both in terms of isolation and thread-safety)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate it; it's default value is null otherwise:

```
public static List<Branch> myArgus = new List<Branch>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You must instansiate `myArgus`:

```
public static List<Branch> myArgus = new List<Branch>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never allocating memory for `myArgus`. Of course it's `null`.

```
public static List<Branch> myArgus = new List<Branch>();
```

You must always make references point to allocated objects in memory, otherwise they cannot be used. Trying to invoke operations on references not pointing to allocated memory will result in `NullPointerException`.